# When I transform a line in snap.svg it rotates back to its original position?

Tags: svg, snap.svg

Trying to make a simple svg animation for a project. I need to take a line, rotate it, and then move it across the screen. I've tried doing this with transform and translate, but the line always rotates back into its original position. How can I move the line without having it rotate back???

Here's my codepen and my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwBXaY

```js
window.onload = function(){

var s = Snap("#svg");


var square = s.select('#square');
var line = s.select('#divide');
var diagonal = s.select('#diagonal');


square.animate({
 opacity:1}, 500);


setTimeout(function() {
  line.animate({
   opacity:1}, 250);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  line.animate({
 transform: 'r-90, 249.25, 506.458'}, 500);
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function() {
  diagonal.animate({
 opacity:1}, 250);
}, 4000);

setTimeout(function() {
  diagonal.animate({
 transform: 'r64, 225.25, 506.458'}, 500);
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
  diagonal.animate({
   transform: 'r-64, 225.25, 506.458',
 transform: 'translate(49, 0)'}, 500);
}, 6000);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id ="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px"
  height="1000px" viewBox="0 0 500 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 500 1000" xml:space="preserve">
  
<rect id="square" class="step1" opacity="0" x="201.25" y="457.458" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" width="98" height="98"/>
  
<line id="divide" class="step2" opacity="0" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" x1="201.25" y1="506.458" x2="299.25" y2="506.458"/>
  
<line id="diagonal" opacity="0" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" x1="201.25" y1="555.458" x2="249.25" y2="457.458"/>
</svg>
```

I want the line that rotates to be horizontal to move halfway across the square, but stay horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure the effect you are after as the line is a different size, if you want to make it a cross in the center of the rect, but you may want to use the intial transform() that you have applied, so it would look like the following when we build up the transfor

```
diagonal.animate({
    transform: 'r-64, 225.25, 506.458',
    transform: 't25,0' + diagonal.transform() +'s0.9'}, 
500);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgWgWe

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well- I just want the line that was a diagonal to move across the screen, in its new horizontal position. When I build up the transform like this it still returns to its original rotation after moving.  `diagonal.animate({
   transform: 'r64, 225.25, 506.458',
 transform: 't49, 0)'}, 500);`

Comment: Transforms are absolute and not relative, so you need to include the previous one on any subsequent transforms.

Comment: thank you! your code really helped, I figured it out